# iphdr required for Raw socket communication

Tags: c, macos, sockets

I am implementing client/server communication using raw sockets. Currently I am making use of 'struct iphdr'. The program runs fine on ubuntu but on OSX I am getting an error as below:
error: incomplete definition of type 'struct iphdr'. The error is generated because of header file mismatch on mac. I am not sure what header files to add to make struct iphdr work in this scenario.

Comment: Can you post some code that exhibits the problem (minimal example)? I just tried this on Yosemite and all I had to include was <netinet/ip.h> and I was able to use struct ip.

Comment: The problem is with struct iphdr and not struct ip.

Comment: On the Mac it's struct ip.